# Magnify text using spy library

Tags: tikz-pgf, spy

I have this information generated using tikz code. I want to magnify some part of the text using the `spy` tikzlibrary, but I am unable to do it. I want to magnify this part of the whole text `4.96 billion`.

Here is my Minimum Working Example:

```
\title{A Very Simple \LaTeXe{} Template}
\author{
}
\date{\today}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=red, text=white]
\begin{tikzpicture}
[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=2,size=2cm,connect spies}]
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
        The Indexed Web contains at least 4.96 billion pages (as of Wednesday, 11 June, 2014). -- WorldWideWebSize.com        
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Did you know?};
\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\spy[red] on (34.5:0.1) in node[right] at (0,-2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Here is what my output looks now, but I am unable to focus on `4.96 billion` and magnify it. In fact, I am not able to magnify any part of this text using `spy` which you can see from the attached photo.
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works after varying the coordinates:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=red, text=white]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  spy using outlines={circle, magnification=2,size=4.5cm,connect spies},
]
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
        The Indexed Web contains at least
        4.96 billion pages (as of
        Wednesday, 11 June, 2014). -- WorldWideWebSize.com
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Did you know?};
\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\spy[red] on (-2.375,.25) in node[right] at (-.5,-3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Rectangular shape

A circle is a little large for the text snippet with its larger width, therefore the following example shows a rectangular shape:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=red, text=white]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=2,size=4.5cm, height=2cm,connect spies},
]
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
        The Indexed Web contains at least
        4.96 billion
        pages (as of
        Wednesday, 11 June, 2014). -- WorldWideWebSize.com
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Did you know?};
\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\spy[red] on (-2.375,.25) in node[right] at (-1,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Rectangle]

### Ellipse

An ellipse requires the library `shapes.geometric`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=red, text=white]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  spy using outlines={ellipse, magnification=2,size=4.5cm, height=2cm,connect spies},
]
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
        The Indexed Web contains at least
        4.96 billion
        pages (as of
        Wednesday, 11 June, 2014). -- WorldWideWebSize.com
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Did you know?};
\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\spy[red] on (-2.375,.25) in node[right] at (-1,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Ellipse]

## Automatic spy position

It would be nice, if the position, which is spied on, could be calculated automatically. TikZ provides option `remember picture`. Then the position of the TikZ picture is written into the `.aux` file (via `\pdfsavepos`). Then named nodes can be referred from another `tikzpicture`, because TikZ knows the absolute coordinates and can calculate the positions.

However there is a catch with library `spy`: It saves the `tikzpicture` into a box and sets it a second time to display the scaled and clipped viewport of the spy window. As a side effect all `\write` whatsits are executed twice including the position markers (but now at a different position). Even worse, the position markers are identified by unique labels. Now they get duplicated with different values. Of course, this disturbs and messes up the result.

The following example uses package `zref-savepos` for the position markers
(Alternatively `\tikzmark` could also be used). Additionally the position definitions in the `.aux` file are wrapped between macros `\auxstartbillion` and `\auxstopbillion`. After the first call, they redefine themselves to ignore their contents, when they are called again. This prevents the duplicate labels.

Also the size of the spy box (options `size` or `width`/`height`) can be calculated. The example below used the rectangle case. A little additional space around the text is added and the scale factor has to be applied.

In case of the circle or ellipse, the size needs to be increased, because the specified size is the size of the overall bounding box, not taking the shape into account.

Because the `.aux` file is involved, two LaTeX runs are needed.

Applied to the example with the rectangle:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\auxstartbillion}{}
\newcommand*{\auxstopbillion}{%
  \def\auxstartbillion##1\auxstopbillion{}%
}
\newcommand*{\auxwrite}[1]{%
  \if@filesw
    \write\@auxout{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\edef\SpyMag{2}
\edef\SpySep{\fboxsep}
\edef\SpyPosX{%
  \the\dimexpr
    (\zposx{billion-ll}sp + \zposx{billion-ur}sp)/2
    - \zposx{billion-origin}sp
  \relax
}
\edef\SpyPosY{%
  \the\dimexpr
    (\zposy{billion-ll}sp + \zposy{billion-ur}sp)/2
    - \zposy{billion-origin}sp
  \relax
}
\edef\SpyWidth{%
  \the\dimexpr(\zposx{billion-ur}sp - \zposx{billion-ll}sp + (\SpySep)*2)
  *\SpyMag\relax
}
\edef\SpyHeight{%
  \the\dimexpr(\zposy{billion-ur}sp - \zposy{billion-ll}sp + (\SpySep)*2)
  *\SpyMag\relax
}
\typeout{[debug] spy on (\SpyPosX, \SpyPosY)}%
\typeout{[debug] spy width=\SpyWidth, height=\SpyHeight}%
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=red, text=white]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  spy using outlines={
    rectangle,
    magnification=2,
    width=\SpyWidth,
    height=\SpyHeight,
    connect spies,
  },
]
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
        The Indexed Web contains at least
        \sbox0{4.96~billion}%
        \auxwrite\auxstartbillion
        \raisebox{-\dp0}[0pt][0pt]{\zsavepos{billion-ll}}%
        \unhcopy0 %
        \raisebox{\ht0}[0pt][0pt]{\zsavepos{billion-ur}}%
        \ % space
        pages (as of
        Wednesday, 11 June, 2014). -- WorldWideWebSize.com
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[overlay](origin) at (0,0) {%
  \zsavepos{billion-origin}%
  \auxwrite\auxstopbillion
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Did you know?};
\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\spy[red] on (\SpyPosX,\SpyPosY) in node[right] at (-1,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Calculated rectangle]